# Patching together emacs buffers and shells outside of emacs

Tags: ess, window-splitting

I'd like to use emacs as a replacement for my current IDE when using R. I like to divide my workspace into three panes:

- Text editor
- R console
- zsh

Previously, I had used tmux to achieve this by patching together these three parts (i.e., three shells running emacs as my editor, an R console, and zsh itself). Nevertheless, I discovered in an [earlier question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/61370/prevent-ess-from-opening-an-r-console/) that it makes more sense for my R console to be running *within* emacs so that the editor and console can interact easily (via ESS-mode). For simplicity in structuring these three panes, I *could* run zsh within emacs, too, but I personally don't like shell-mode and prefer to use a regular zsh outside of emacs. (Apologies if this is sacrilege around these parts.)

**Q**: Is there a way that I can structure these three panels, as shown below, where the dashed line indicates buffers within emacs?

[image]

Comment: Not an answer, but consider `vterm` which provides a very capable terminal emulator inside emacs.

Comment: @FranBurstall Whoa – `vterm` is _much_ nicer than shell-mode. I think this may solve my problem. Thanks, Fran!